# Flex build use local files

Tags: apache-flex, release, local-files

I have a very stupid problem. I'm using Flash Builder (Flex) 4.

My application displays a video using VideoDisplay component and some images.
The video filename is always named video.mp4 and the images are inside a folder called "real/".
The video file and the real folder are in the **SAME** location of the .swf built.

The video source in the code is set like this:

```
videoDisplay.source = 'video.mp4';
```

and the images, loaded dynamically, are like:

```
img.source = 'real/' + imageFilename;
```

In **development**, I put this video and real folder inside the Flash Builder folder called bin-debug: I can **correctly** display the video and see the images.

In the **release** version, when you export and build the release, I have tried to put this video file and the folder inside the folder bin-release, I open the index.html generated, but **nothing**, the video and the images are not loaded!

Is there any problem with the sandbox? I don't think so because it is in the same local folder!

Do I have to setup anything in the compiler? Some param?

Comment: Have you tried actually putting the release build on the server?

Comment: Is your HTML file, containing SWF, located in the same folder as SWF itself?

Answer (score -1):

use URLRequest to load the external files

```
new URLRequest("c:\folder\video.mp4"));
```

Comment: -1.  That is wrong, you can't do a URL request to a local file for a web app.